# std::unique_ptr and custom deleters

Tags: c++, unique-ptr

Scott Meyer’s “Effective Modern C++” discusses the use of `std::unique_ptr` with custom deleter and states:

> Deleters that are function pointers generally cause the size of a `std::unique_ptr` to grow from one
>   word to two. For deleters that are function objects, the change in size depends on how much state is stored in the function object. Stateless function objects (e.g., from lambda expressions with no captures) incur no size penalty, and this means that when a custom deleter can be implemented as either a function or a captureless lambda expression, the lambda is preferable.

As an example, this:

```
auto delInvmt1 = [](Investment* pInvestment) {
makeLogEntry(pInvestment);
delete pInvestment;
};

template<typename... Ts>
std::unique_ptr<Investment, decltype(delInvmt1)>
makeInvestment(Ts&&... args);
```

is better than this:

```
void delInvmt2(Investment* pInvestment) {
    makeLogEntry(pInvestment);
    delete pInvestment;
}

template<typename... Ts>
std::unique_ptr<Investment, void (*)(Investment*)>
makeInvestment(Ts&&... params);
```

I can see that in the second case a pointer to the deleter function needs to be stored in the `unique_ptr`, but why does nothing similar need to be stored for the lambda case?

Comment: `std::unique_ptr` is using Empty Base Optimization, which allows storing empty objects (that is, of classes with no data members) with no additional size overhead.

Comment: In the first case, the logic is part of the *type*, the the second, it's part of the *value*.

Answer (score 3):

As @milleniumbug said, `std::unique_ptr` use `Empty Base Optimization`. It means you can declare a class with no data member:

```
class empty
{
public:
   // methods
};
```

If you have another class that declare a member variable of `empty` inside it, the size of your class will increase even if `empty` has no data member:

```
class foo
{
public:
    int i;
    empty em;
};
```

In this case size of `foo` will be 8 byte. But if you declare `foo` to inherit from `empty`, this inheritance has no effect in size of `foo` and it's size will be 4 byte:

```
class foo : public empty 
{
public:
    int i;
};
```

If you take a look into `std::unique_ptr` implementation of your compiler you will see this. I'm using VC++ 2015 and in this compiler structure of `std::unique_ptr` is like below:

```
template<class _Ty, class _Dx>  // = default_delete<_Ty>
class unique_ptr : public _Unique_ptr_base<_Ty, _Dx>
```

It inherit from this class:

```
template<class _Ty, class _Dx>
class _Unique_ptr_base
{   // stores pointer and deleter
 public:
 ...
 _Compressed_pair<_Dx, pointer> _Mypair;
};
```

In `_Unique_ptr_base` there is a member of type `_Compressed_pair`. This class is declared in this way:

```
template<class _Ty1, class _Ty2, bool = is_empty<_Ty1>::value && !is_final<_Ty1>::value>
class _Compressed_pair final
    : private _Ty1

{   // store a pair of values, deriving from empty first
private:
     _Ty2 _Myval2;
```

Actually this class is specialized if it's second template argument is an empty class. In this case it inherit from empty deleter class and declare a member variable of first template argument that is `std::unique_ptr` pointer.